# Python 2 : Tkinter Button Response is very Slow

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter

I am trying to create number of buttons on a grid using for loop. I want that if I click on a button, it will print number associated to that button. It is working fine, but only when I clicking it slowly (taking time interval of about half second before clicking next button).
When I clicking the buttons fast i.e less time gap. it is not print value, even after getting clicked. Please advice.

```
from Tkinter import *

def hl_buttons(hl_list = None):
    hl_list = ['0','1','2',]
    row = 1
    selected_num = []
    for hl_num in hl_list:
        button = Button(frame, text='Button'+str(hl_num), command= lambda tckt = hl_num : on_click_hl_buttons(tckt))
        button.grid(row=row, column=0)
        row += 1

def on_click_hl_buttons(tckt = None):
    print tckt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    frame = Tk()
    frame.wm_title("App")
    hl_buttons()
    frame.mainloop()
```

I have also tried it in Python 3.x with tkinter. No luck :(

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem on my machine.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ - There are three buttons : Button0, Button1 and Button2. If you click on Button0 then, within fraction of second , click Button 1 and then again Button2, you get only '2' in output as '2' is associated with Button2. If you click each button after 1 second, it will give output as '0', '1' and '2'. Please try this.

Comment: Its resolved now. There is some issue with my laptop track pad I guess. When I am using wireless mouse, its working fine.